# Реализация Undo/Redo

Tags: c#, bitmap, picturebox, drawbitmap

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо последний нарисованный объект в Bitmap. 
Сложность в том, что прорисовка одного объекта состоит из нескольких операций, про которые пользователю не нужно знать. Заранее прошу прощение, если где-то не корректно выразился.
Вот пример одного из методов:

```
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
        x1 = x1 * razmer_setki;
        x2 = x2 * razmer_setki;
        y2 = y1 * razmer_setki;
        y1 = y2 - razmer_setki;
        PointF point1 = new PointF(x1, y1);
        PointF point2 = new PointF(x2, y2);
        PointF point3 = new PointF(x1, y2);
        PointF point4 = new PointF(x2, y1);
        PointF[] curvePoints = { point3, point2, point4, point3, point1, point4 };
        g.DrawLines(TrainPen, curvePoints);
        point2 = new PointF(x2 - 1, y2 - 1);
        point3 = new PointF(x1 + 1, y2);
        point4 = new PointF(x2 - 1, y1 + 1);
        PointF[] curvePoints2 = { point3, point2, point4, point3 };
        g.FillPolygon(TrainBrush, curvePoints2);
        String drawString = Pogruzka.Text;
        Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 8);
        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        PointF drawPoint = new PointF(x1, y1);
        g.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint);
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        g.Dispose();
```

Если я правильно понял, то все операции надо сохранять где-либо, но как это в моём случае лучше реализовать?

Comment: Да, операции нужно сохранять. Либо операции, либо "кадры" плодить (последнее проще, но занимает больше памяти).

Comment: Можно подробнее про "кадры". Если правильно понял, сохранять последний bitmap отдельно и при необходимости заменять им?

Comment: Да, делать копию Bitmap в массив "истории".

Comment: Спасибо, за совет. Буду про бывать реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

```
Stack<Bitmap> bmpstack = new Stack<Bitmap>();//Объявляем сам стек

//создает копию Bitmap'a и заносит её в стек
var copy = bmp.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), bmp.PixelFormat);
bmpstack.Push(copy);
if (Undo.Enabled == false)
    Undo.Enabled = true;

//Извлекает из стека Bitmap и присваивает его PictureBox'У
if (bmpstack.Count > 0)
{
   bmp = bmpstack.Pop();
   pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}
if (bmpstack.Count == 0)
   Undo.Enabled = false;
```

Получилось реализовать так. Но это только Undo, откат действий. С повтором не стал возиться, т.к. мне он не нужен.

Comment: На всякий случай: есть паттерн Команда, там как раз для вашего случая, сам недавно с этим возился.

Comment: Я не до конца понял как с ним работать, на тот момент, и реализовал таким образом. Но всё равно спасибо